# How to filter a query with partial string matches in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm using the below code to filter a query, however it only returns exact matches. If I want to look at every person with John in their name, how would I change this?

```
With Me
    .Filter = "[Initiator's Name]='John'"
    .FilterOn = True
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
With Me
    .Filter = "[Initiator's Name] LIKE '*John*'"
    .FilterOn = True
End With
```